# Link Google benchmark with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, microbenchmark, google-benchmark

I try to compile my project including `google benchmark`. This is the project structure:

```
$proj:
|_ benchmark
|_ include
|_ src
|_ CMakeLists.txt
```

Into the folder `include` I add `google benchmark` as `submodule` linked to the latest release [@73d4d5e](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/703bd9caab50b139428cea1aaff9974ebee5742e). Instead, inside the `benchmark` folder I put these two files:

**benchmark/first.cpp** (It is the repository usage example)

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void BM_StringCreation(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state)
    std::string empty_string;
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_StringCreation);

// Define another benchmark
static void BM_StringCopy(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::string x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state)
    std::string copy(x);
}
BENCHMARK(BM_StringCopy);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_BENCH_CPP *.cpp)

foreach(ONE_BENCH_CPP ${ALL_BENCH_CPP})

  get_filename_component(ONE_BENCH_EXEC ${ONE_BENCH_CPP} NAME_WE)
  set(TARGET_NAME Benchmark_${ONE_BENCH_EXEC})

  add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${ONE_BENCH_CPP})
  set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${ONE_BENCH_EXEC}) 
  target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ../include/benchmark/include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
  target_link_libraries(
    ${TARGET_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
  )

endforeach()
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` file on the root of the project, I add the compile flag:

```
[...]
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -lbenchmark -lpthread -fopenmp")
[...]
```

but the flag `-lbenchmark` is not found. The compilation return this error:

> ld: library not found for -lbenchmark

If I omit the flag, during the compilation I have this output:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> [build]   "__ZN9benchmark10InitializeEPiPPc", referenced from:
> [build]       _main in first.cpp.o
> [build]   "__ZN9benchmark22RunSpecifiedBenchmarksEv", referenced from:
> [build]       _main in first.cpp.o
> [build]   "__ZN9benchmark27ReportUnrecognizedArgumentsEiPPc", referenced from:
> [build]       _main in first.cpp.o
> [build]   "__ZN9benchmark5State16StartKeepRunningEv", referenced from:
> [build]       __ZL17BM_StringCreationRN9benchmark5StateE in first.cpp.o
> [build]       __ZL13BM_StringCopyRN9benchmark5StateE in first.cpp.o
> [...]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/benchmark#usage-with-cmake

You'll want another `target_link_libraries` pointing at the benchmark library rather than trying to set it using `-l`. CMake will take care of the command line for you then.

Comment: If I add `target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} benchmark::benchmark)` after the other `targer_link_library` I have this error: `CMake Error at benchmark/CMakeLists.txt:8 (add_executable):Target "Benchmark_small_dyna_dbg" links to target "benchmark::benchmark"
but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?`. And the `find_packege` not the resolvw the problem.

Comment: this seems like a more general cmake configuration issue than specific to benchmark. Either the `find_package` you've added isn't finding the package (i'd expect an error in your cmake logs) or maybe you have an older benchmark version when the target was just `benchmark` rather than `benchmark::benchmark`?

Comment: I add to my project ony the latest relase of benchmar (with git submodule). I also add the gtest library also as a git submodule. This could be the problem? Can yoi give me an example of cmake for my project structure?